# Convert unicode chars in xml to ascii

Tags: objective-c, xml, escaping

InDesign can export an XML file, and it will also "Remap break, whitespace, and special characters" if you check the box to do that. How can I do the same thing on text?

For example, if I have: •this is a bullet —long dash

InDesign exports as: &# 8226;this is a bullet &# 8212;long dash

I don't know what kind of encoding this is. Can a standard Objective-C class do this (working on OS X) or a third party library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are an HTML thing. People usually refer to as HTML encoding but technically, they are [Numeric character references](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.3.1). There is nothing built into Foundation that decodes them, but if you look around you can find some code to handle it (for example, https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.m).